# Laravel add data after migrate cause error

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add these data after `refresh` or `database` `migration`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('type');
            $table->integer('pid')->default(0);
            $table->integer('cid')->default(0);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::table('locations')->insert([
            ['type' => 1, 'name' => 'Istanbul'],
            ['type' => 2, 'name' => 'Istanbul', 'pid' => 1],
            ['type' => 3, 'name' => 'Taksim', 'cid' => 2],
            ['type' => 3, 'name' => 'Beyoglu', 'cid' => 2],
        ]);
    }
```

but it give me this error:

> ?[41;1m Illuminate\Database\QueryException ?[49;22m :
>   ?[33mSQLSTATE[42S01]: Ba se table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'locations' already exists (SQL: cre ate table `locations` (`id`
>   bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,  `type` int not
>   null, `pid` int not null default '0', `cid` int not null default  '0',
>   `name` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` ti mestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

How can I solve this?

Comment: don't put db insert in migration use db seed, to add data in your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `DB:table` from your migration and run:

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

**Then**

```
php artisan make:seed LocationTableSeeder
```

**Then** add this to `run()` function:

```
    DB::table('locations')->insert([
        ['type' => 1, 'name' => 'Istanbul', 'pid' => 0, 'cid' => 0, 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')],
        ['type' => 2, 'name' => 'Istanbul', 'pid' => 1, 'cid' => 0, 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')],
        ['type' => 3, 'name' => 'Taksim', 'cid' => 2, 'pid' => 0, 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')],
        ['type' => 3, 'name' => 'Beyoglu', 'cid' => 2, 'pid' => 0, 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')],
    ]);
```

**Then**

```
php artisan db:seed --class=LocationTableSeeder
```

Comment: Still got error `Insert value list does not match column list:`

Comment: @tourtravel The error is pretty clear, what you want to insert does not match to your columns. add `pid` and `cid` and also `updated_at` `created_at` check updated answer